# ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['SMA_200'], dtype='object')

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Disponemos de este DataFrame.

```
# Simulador decotizaciones
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def crear_df_cotizaciones():
    rango = ['2014-01-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-03-01', '2014-04-01',
                   '2014-05-01', '2014-06-01', '2014-07-01', '2014-08-01',
                   '2014-09-01', '2014-10-01', '2014-11-01', '2014-12-01',
                   '2015-01-01', '2015-02-01', '2015-03-01', '2015-04-01',
                   '2015-05-01', '2015-06-01', '2015-07-01', '2015-08-01',
                   '2015-09-01', '2015-10-01', '2015-11-01', '2015-12-01',
                   '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-04-01',
                   '2016-05-01', '2016-06-01']
    valores = [100.0,99.97,99.96,99.95,99.94,99.92,99.9,99.84,99.94,100.82,100.62,100.63,100.84,100.72,
               100.61,100.7,100.63,100.08,100.22,100.09,99.79,99.42,99.42,99.3,98.88,98.63,98.62,99.55,99.24,99.33]
    df_cotizaciones = pd.DataFrame(valores, index = rango)
    df_cotizaciones.reset_index(inplace = True)
    df_cotizaciones.columns = ["Date", "Close"]
    df_cotizaciones['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_cotizaciones['Date'], errors='coerce')
    df_cotizaciones.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
    return df_cotizaciones

df_cotizaciones = crear_df_cotizaciones()
```

Quiero crear una clase para el cálculo y la gráfica de las Medias Móviles Simples, de la siguiente manera.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Calculador_SMA:
    def __init__(self, periods, datos_sma):
        self.periods = periods
        self.datos_sma = datos_sma

    def calcular_SMA(self):
        SMA = pd.Series(self.datos_sma['Close'].rolling(self.periods, min_periods=self.periods).mean(), name='SMA_' + str(periods))
        self.datos_sma = self.datos_sma.join(SMA)

    def plot_SMA(self):
        plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
        plt.plot(self.datos_sma.index, self.datos_sma['Close'], label='Cotización', lw=1.5)
        plt.plot(self.datos_sma.index, self.datos_sma['SMA_' + str(self.periods)], label='SMA_' + str(self.periods), lw=1.5)
        plt.title(value_name + f" Price History with SMA of {self.periods} days", fontsize=10, backgroundcolor='yellow')
        plt.xlabel('Fecha', fontsize=10)
        plt.ylabel('Precio', fontsize=10)
        plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=8)

        # Ajustar tamaño de las fechas en la escala x
        plt.gca().xaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=8)
    
        # Ajustar tamaño de los números en la escala y
        plt.gca().yaxis.set_tick_params(labelsize=8)
        plt.show()        
          
# Parámetros
periods = 200
sma_calc = Calculador_SMA(periods, datos_sma)

df_sma = sma_calc.calcular_SMA()
sma_calc.plot_SMA()
```

Me devuelve.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_6131/4266711177.py in <module>
     31 sma_calc = Calculador_SMA(periods, datos_sma)
     32 
---> 33 df_sma = sma_calc.calcular_SMA()
     34 sma_calc.plot_SMA()
     35 

/tmp/ipykernel_6131/4266711177.py in calcular_SMA(self)
      9     def calcular_SMA(self):
     10         SMA = pd.Series(self.datos_sma['Close'].rolling(self.periods, min_periods=self.periods).mean(), name='SMA_' + str(periods))
---> 11         self.datos_sma = self.datos_sma.join(SMA)
     12 
     13     def plot_SMA(self):

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in join(self, other, on, how, lsuffix, rsuffix, sort)
   9261         5  K1  A5   B1
   9262         """
-> 9263         return self._join_compat(
   9264             other, on=on, how=how, lsuffix=lsuffix, rsuffix=rsuffix, sort=sort
   9265         )

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _join_compat(self, other, on, how, lsuffix, rsuffix, sort)
   9292                     sort=sort,
   9293                 )
-> 9294             return merge(
   9295                 self,
   9296                 other,

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in merge(left, right, how, on, left_on, right_on, left_index, right_index, sort, suffixes, copy, indicator, validate)
    120         validate=validate,
    121     )
--> 122     return op.get_result()
    123 
    124 

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in get_result(self)
    716         join_index, left_indexer, right_indexer = self._get_join_info()
    717 
--> 718         llabels, rlabels = _items_overlap_with_suffix(
    719             self.left._info_axis, self.right._info_axis, self.suffixes
    720         )

~/anaconda3/envs/enri/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _items_overlap_with_suffix(left, right, suffixes)
   2315 
   2316     if not lsuffix and not rsuffix:
-> 2317         raise ValueError(f"columns overlap but no suffix specified: {to_rename}")
   2318 
   2319     def renamer(x, suffix):

ValueError: columns overlap but no suffix specified: Index(['SMA_200'], dtype='object')
```

¿Cuál es la causa de este error?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Comment: Buen día, ¿De dónde sale `datos_sma`? ¿Son los mismos datos que `df_cotizaciones`?

Comment: Otra cosa, probé tu código pero no me devuelve el error que mencionas, devuelve otro ya que `value_name` no existe pero lo estás utilizando. Por favor oprime [edit] y agrega un ejemplo completo con el que podamos reproducir el problema.

Comment: Gracias. Voy a revisarlo en origen y modificar lo ue sea necesario para reproducir el error,o cerrar esta pregunta .